# When are statistics created?

Tags: sql-server-2012, index, ssms, statistics

I know that when we create an index then statistics are automatically created. My question is: Is it the only case when statistics are created? I remember that once I found on the internet that we have column statistics along with index statistics. Could you please enlighten me regarding this topic? When I execute the below script I get the following result:

```
use movies
go
EXEC sp_helpstats
@objname = '[dbo].[actors]',
@results = 'ALL';
```

This object does not have any statistics or indexes.

Answer (score 4):

Column statistics are created automatically as needed by SQL Server when the [`AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-2017#auto_create_statistics) database option is `ON` and also by an explict [`CREATE STATISTICS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-statistics-transact-sql) statement.

With the `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` database option, the query optimizer will create single column stats during query compilation as needed on columns specified in query predicates when a stats histogram on the leading column doesn't already exist and that information is useful in plan selection (i.e. non-trivial plan).

Statistics may also be created beforehand using `CREATE STATISTICS`. Unlike auto-created statistics, `CREATE STATISTICS` allows one to create statistics on multiple columns to provide better estimates for compound predicates (e.g. `FirstName = 'John' and LastName = 'Doh'`).